# Hiding (Not Removing) all HTML tags - Jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I go about hiding all HTML tags using jquery. Not removing but hiding. Would I have to individually specify each tag or is there a more robust/scalable solution?

**Example String:**

```
My name is <b>Joe</b> and I like <span style="color:red;">long walks</span> on the <i>beach</i>.
```

**Result**

```
My name is and I like on the .
```

Comment: What do you mean?  I think you actually do want to remove them, and keep both versions in variables.

Comment: I just want to hide them only. Is that possible?

Comment: Hide _all_ HTML tags?  For what purpose?

Comment: The answers all make it clear that `.hide()` is the method you're looking for, but since nobody mentioned anything about showing the elements again later: for that you'd use `.show()`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide all the child elements of a specific parent.

Since the descendants of hidden elements will not be shown anyway, there is no need to iterate over all of them with `find("*")`:

```
$("#theParent").children().hide();
```

Or, alternatively, as gdoron suggests:

```
$("#theParent > *").hide();
```

The above might be faster since it uses a pure CSS selector.

Comment: I think `$('#parent > *').hide();` should be the fastest way.

Comment: @Joe. No, it is fine like it is now.

Answer (score 4):

`$('*').hide()` would remove ALL tags for the all document. `$('#parent *').hide()` all element inside a parent element.

Comment: I think `$('#parent > *').hide()` should be the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to hide the descendants of a particular containing element.

```
$(container).find('*').hide();
```

jQuery also has a shorthand form for this:

```
$('*', container).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `$('p *').hide()` if the whole text is in a `<p>` element.

If you only want to hide them, but still take up space, set their visibility to hidden

```
$('p *').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

The elements will still take up space, but won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy as long as you have a parent container :)

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    My name is <b>Joe</b> and I like <span style="color:red;">long walks</span> on the <i>beach</i>.
</div>

<script>
    $('#myDiv:child').hide();
</script>
```